# how to insert three figures in a presentation?

Tags: graphics, presentations

I want to insert three figures in a presentation, is anybody have any suggestion ? one on top and two side by side in down. 
I would like to first show the two down and after the one in top appear.

This gives me an error

photoHL60 is the name of photo

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
         \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
             \uncover<2->{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photoHL60.png}
             \caption{HL60}}
             \label{fig:a}
         \end{subfigure}%

         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
             \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photoPC3.png}}
             \caption{PC3}
             \label{fig:b}
         \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
             \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{photoMCF7.png}}
             \caption{MCF7}
             \label{fig:c}
         \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: @samcarter oh sure sorry for that, I liked and accepted the answer

Comment: @Learner Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a starting point. Change the measurement units to more robust ones based on your needs. To uncover the figures incrementally, use `uncover` command!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
         \uncover<2->{\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}}\\
            \vspace{1em}
         \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=4cm]{example-image-b}}
            \hspace{0.8cm}
         \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=4cm]{example-image-c}}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have captioned graphics, you can use `figure` and `subfigure` environments. You can also `minipage`s if you want to have more freedom in positioning. You should first load proper packages

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

and then create a `frame` like so:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
         \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
             \uncover<2->{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
             \caption{A random caption}}
             \label{fig:a}
         \end{subfigure}%

         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
             \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
             \caption{Foo}
             \label{fig:b}
         \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
             \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
             \caption{Bar}
             \label{fig:c}
         \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: that is very good thanks! however can you please add the caption to each of them and also the same size for A? I will accept your answer

Comment: @Nemo, check the updated answer. Cheers!

Comment: why does it make the figures appear in two pages ? I only need to present the three figures once in one page

Comment: it also gives me an error, look at above to see the exact code and see whether I made any mistake

Comment: They appear in two pages because you mentioned you want them to be shown sequentially. Note that the page number doesn't change so when you go through your slides, it mimics the effect of showing photos one after the other. As for the error, you need to tell me what is the error since I don't see anything in your question/comment. Did you add the packages?

Comment: subcaption errro: this package can't be used in cooperation (sub caption) with the subfig package / l.54 \endinput}{}

Comment: that was the error, what If i show them once and not in two pages ?